# arc animation with createJS

Tags: createjs

I am trying to animate arc with createJS library, but i always have a mistake like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: **context.graphics.clearRect** is not a function

and

> Uncaught TypeError: **context.graphics.beginPath** is not a function

what does that mean? help me please

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 body {
   background: #f1ecec;
}
 canvas {background-color: aliceblue;}
    </style>
        <script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.05.21.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

var context = new createjs.Shape();
var x = 250;
var y = 250;
var radius = 75;
var endPercent = 25 * Math.PI;
var curPerc = Math.PI / 2;
var counterClockwise = false;
var circ = Math.PI * 2;
var quart = Math.PI / 2;



context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = '#ad2323';
context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
context.shadowBlur = 10;
context.shadowColor = '#656565';


function animate(current) {
 context.graphics.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 context.graphics.beginPath();
 context.graphics.arc(x, y, radius, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, false);
context.graphics.stroke();
 curPerc++;
 if (curPerc < endPercent) {
     requestAnimationFrame(function () {
         animate(curPerc / 100)
     });
   }
 }
animate();
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a combination of Graphics APIs and Context2D APIs, and you're trying to do so on both your Shape instance and its Graphics object. You also haven't added the Shape to the Stage, and you aren't calling `stage.update` anywhere.

I'd recommend taking a look at some simple drawing examples to get started. For instance (all in the GitHub repo):

- tutorials/Getting Started
- examples/Graphics_simple.html
- examples/APITest.html

Then, check out the docs for more info:
http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not using the createjs library as intended

Here is how I would handle animating an arc. I create a shape, add a "deg" property onto it to tween and use createjs.Tween's "change" event to clear and draw the new arc based on the deg property

```
        function degreesToRadians(deg){
            return deg * Math.PI / 180;
        }

        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

        var s = new createjs.Shape();
        s.x = s.y = 50;
        stage.addChild(s);

        var arcSize = 20;
        s.deg = 0;
        s.tween = new createjs.Tween.get(s, { override: true })
            .to({deg: 360 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.quartOut)
            .on("change", function () { 
                   this.graphics.clear().beginFill("red").moveTo(0, 0).arc(0, 0, arcSize, degreesToRadians(0), degreesToRadians(this.deg)); 
            }, s); // second param is scope for the function


        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", function(){
            stage.update();
        });
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks! This is useful for creating a circular animating timer

Comment: I wonder how can I make it so the "lips" are on top instead of on the right side tho

Comment: @IamL you can set the rotation of the shape s.rotation = -90 this will move the lips to the top